# How do I isolate tests for CRUD App in Playwright

Tags: postgresql, next.js, playwright, e2e

The Playwright docs say that each tests should be isolated so tests can run in parallel, and intuitively I agree with that, but I'm having problems at a practical level. My first try at isolating my tests is to truncate the table (clear all records) after each test, and then my update and delete tests add records to work with.

Truncating the table lets me test the "there are no records" state and prevents failures when adding users because the user was already added on a previous run or by a previous browser.

However, these tests collide pretty hard when run in parallel, and they even collide when I don't "chain" the projects by setting each browser as dependent on the previous one (probably I should just set everything to not be parallel, but I haven't taken that step yet).

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around what it means to "isolate" the tests. If I write a user for beforeEach, and then a different test concludes by truncating the table, then OF COURSE my update test is going to fail when the test actually runs and the record that was just created was already truncated. I'm completely at a loss about how you truly isolate tests when you need to test an absolutely clean state but also need to work with existing records. How are others doing this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Serial mode for interdependent tests

I would use [serial mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#serial-mode) in that scenario to keep all those interdependent tests in same file and to execute them in the defined order.

I think there is no such thing as `best practice` but `good practices in an given context`. Ultimately we need to find an right balance in an given context.

In general, I would strive for independent tests so that they don't affect other tests however in this scenario it makes sense to have them as dependent tests in a single file.

Example:

```
test.describe.serial('FeaturePage', () => {
      let page;
      let featurePage;
    
      test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
        page = await browser.newPage();
        featurePage = new FeaturePage(page);
      });
    
      test('Does thing A', ({ page }) => {
        await featurePage.doThingA();
      });
      
      test('Does thing B', ({ page }) => {
        await featurePage.doThingB();
      });
      
      test('Does thing C', ({ page }) => {
        await featurePage.doThingC();
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like there's no easy way to run your tests in parallel since they all use a single table and are dependent on server-side state.

If these are tests of a web app UI, I would consider if they truly need to interact with the backend. Perhaps you can limit the test to verifying whether the application sends the correct CRUD requests (see [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#mock-apis)) - assert on their payload, url, headers and whatever else you find relevant and abort them so that there is no actual server-side interaction.

Then for tests that require a certain state you can mock the API response to provide that state.

Comment: The problem is I want to verify that the UI draws the right thing starting from and empty state and also starting with a full state. Because it's a Next 13 project, there's not always a clear demarcation between the server and the client (if there were, I'd just be using Jest like normal--not an e2e testing FW), so I can't just send empty data into a component or populated data into a component.

Answer (score -1):

Mocking API calls would allow you to intercept certain HTTP requests and send the desired response back to the browser, simulating a successful CRUD operation independent from the status of the database

The playwright documentation covers how to implement mock API calls here: https://playwright.dev/docs/mock